# Python - BeautifulSoup: find td width

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have many tables and each has table data tag something like this:

```
<td width="563" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFF99" class="text">
...
<td width="12" bgcolor="#FFFF99" class="lettnav">
<td bgcolor="#FFFF99" class="lettnav">
```

The goal is to locate which `<td>` with the highest value. To do that, first I want to get the value of the width using beautifulsoap (if no with just print empty string).

Here is my code snippet that so far did not work:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
cells = soup.findAll("td",{"width": re.compile('\d')})

for aCell in cells:
   width=aCell.find("width")
   print(width)
```

Any help?

Comment: What did not work? Do u get an empty list of cells or u cannot extract the width within the for loop?

Comment: It does not give me the width

Answer (score 1):

To find the *td* with the largest width you can use *max* on the list of *td's* returned from the *find_all* call, setting the key to `key=lambda t: int(t["width"])`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
cells = soup.find_all("td", width=True)

mx_td = max(cells, key=lambda t: int(t["width"]))
```

`t["width"]` accesses the *attribute* value, we need to call *int* on the result or the value would be compared [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) i.e `2 > 100` would be True.

Answer (score 0):

In BeautifulSoup attributes are accessed in dict notation (see https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes for more information).

Using `width=aCell["width"]` your code works:

```
for aCell in cells:
    width=aCell["width"]
    print(width)
```

If you're just interested in the max value you could also omit the `for` loop and use a list comprehension instead:

```
maxwidth = max(int(x["width"]) for x in cells)
```